# How to import bookmarks.htm into Google bookmarks (NOT Chrome bookmarks)

Tags: import, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

You can export from https://www.google.com/bookmarks/ because there is an option at the bottom of the list, called "export bookmarks"... but ... you cannot import from a list i.e. bookmarks.htm generated from another browser's bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import bookmarks into the history of alien account if that's what you are asking. All you can do is re-import your exported bookmarks the standard route and then let Google sync it between your browser and your account

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but as I said, I'm NOT asking about chrome bookmarks. It's about 'google bookmarks', that's another product !